# Plotly's Sankey diagram ignores X and Y coordinates

Tags: python, plotly

I'm trying to visualise a change in ranking over time periods. I've settled on a Sankey diagram being the best way to achieve this (but still open to suggestions).

The problem I'm having with Plotly's Sankey visualisation (Python version) is that I believe the X and Y coordinates are being overriden by the layout algorithm.

Some sample data:

```
import pandas as pd
inputs = [
    ("Rod", "2019", 1),
    ("Jane", "2019", 2),
    ("Rod", "2020", 1),
    ("Jane", "2020", 2),
    ("Freddy", "2020", 3),  # This is a new entry in 2020
    ("Jane", "2021", 1),
    ("Freddy", "2021", 2),
    ("Rod", "2021", 3),   
]
demo_df = pd.DataFrame(inputs, columns=["name", "year", "rank"])
demo_df.index.name = "node_id"
demo_df
```

[image]

Then the Plotly code to visualise:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Sankey(
    arrangement = "snap",
    node = {
        "label": demo_df["name"],
        "x": [0, 0, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1, 1, 1],  # A 'column' based on the year
        "y": [0, 0.5, 0, 0.5, 1, 0, 0.5, 1],  # A 'row' based on rank for that year
        "color": "blue"
    },
    link = {
        "source": [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
        "target": [2, 3, 7, 5, 6],
        "value": [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
    }
  )])


fig.show()
```

Output:

[image]

If the X / Y values were followed as defined, "Rod" in the central column would be at the top with a Y value of `0`.

Is there any way to force or override this?

Answer (score 1):

I would call this either a bug in the plotly Python library or insufficient error handling, but it has been reported in the github repo:

https://github.com/plotly/plotly.py/issues/3002

For some reason, no exception is thrown even though it seems like node positions of `0` for Sankey diagrams are not supported.  Following the example in the issue linked above:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Sankey(
    arrangement = "snap",
    node = {
        "label": demo_df["name"],
        "x": [1e-9, 1e-9, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1, 1, 1],  # A 'column' based on the year
        "y": [1e-9, 0.5, 1e-9, 0.5, 1, 1e-9, 0.5, 1],  # A 'row' based on rank for that year
        "color": "blue"
    },
    link = {
        "source": [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
        "target": [2, 3, 7, 5, 6],
        "value": [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
    }
  )])


fig.show()
```

in Plotly 5.1.0 gives the following output for me.

[image: sankey_fixed_positions]